# Pros and cons of Blackberry Playbook QNX OS using Adobe Air for Application Development

Tags: tablet, blackberry, adobe-air

I was quite surprised to see the BlackBerry Playbook tablet using Adobe Air as the developer platform in the new QNX OS. I've also heard that future BlackBerry phones will also use the QNX OS, meaning they too will rely on Adobe Air for application development. What are the pros and cons you see for this decision by RIM?

Answer (score 1):

One HUGE plus for this move to Adobe Air is that creating GUIs for Playbook (and future handsets running QNX) will be vastly easier. UI on a BlackBerry has always been one of the bigger pain points of developing for BB.

Comment: And possibly cross platform!